# Why is there no notion of size in modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I was reading this from this website (https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/arith.html).

Why can't we say that $a < b$ if the least residue class for $a$ is smaller than the least residue class for $b$. Wouldn't this establish a size ordering?

Comment: Size has nothing to do with this. The author is explaining why those sets are not ordered.

Comment: What you describe would indeed be an "order" in some weak sense. However, it lacks many of the properties that the usual order of the integers has. For example, if $a,b,c$ are integers and $a<b$, then $a+c < b+c$. This property does not hold for your "order", as the example from the text indicates. This means that this order says nothing about "sizes"; big things added together could be small. It is thus not natural to view the residue classes mod $n$ as ordered in the way you describe. Thinking about them as lying on a circle, as the text suggests, is much more intuitive

Comment: By the linked dupe, an abelian group can be linearly ordered iff it is torsion-free. This is what is meant by the quoted statement.

Comment: @BillDubuque Don't you think it's counterproductive to link a question that is above the complexity of the question being asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is not very precise with their terminology, because the usual term used for the property that he's describing is a [linearly ordered group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group).

The point is not that you can't order this set, as you have indeed come up with one. The problem is that this ordering is not compatible with the algebraic operations on the set, in the sense that if $a < b$ then we would expect $a+c < b+c$, in cases where it makes sense to talk about $a+c$ and $b+c$.

The notion of group operations and ordering are both exemplified in the real numbers or integers, where they are compatible. However, in the way they are defined in the most general sense, they are not usually compatible. Since in the case of modular arithmetic it's more important to study the algebraic structure, we usually choose not to put an ordering on it.